# How can I exclude a duplicated ActionBar class from my dependencies in android?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

How can I overcome this error? Is there someway to exclude ActionBar? I get the same error whetherI use a jar or dependency.

Here is the error I receive:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
 android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.class
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle